# Problem:- could not create type

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I had made some kinds on web services. These are working fine locally. I uploaded the web services and other required folders and files on the site. When now I write the url for any services then I get a error like

```
Parser Error Message: Could not create type 'ESL.EslClass'.
```

I didn't understand, that why this error is coming.

If anyone has any idea for this problem, please reply.

Answer (score 3):

Things to check:

the obvious stuff ...

- Do you have the right framework version installed on the server?

Security settings ...

- Can the app run?
- Can it run all its dependencies?

More complex stuff ...

- Is this type in a library within the bin folder of the application?
- if not, is the dependant application requirements installed on the
  server?

To help you further i would ask ...

- Can you get any more detail about the error?

Can you install the remote debugging service on the server and then attach visual studio to it ... that might give you a bit more detail on the error.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I got the solution for this problem. As you mention above things. All things were included and working fine. This problem was due to sub domain setting.

Comment: sounds complex ... but at least you got your solution :)